# Web pages not appearing

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, wireless, internet

I have both `12.04` and `11.10` installed on the same machine. Internet (both wireless and wired) isn't working on `12.04`. Any help?

`lshw -C network`

```
PCI (sysfs)  
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82567LF-2 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:21:9b:1b:9e:31
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=1.5.1-k firmware=1.8-5 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:43 memory:f9dc0000-f9ddffff memory:f9df4000-f9df4fff ioport:a080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR5418 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5008E 802.11(a)bgn] (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:22:b0:ce:f1:ff
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.2.0-24-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.129 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:f9ef0000-f9efffff
```

`IWCONFIG`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"FASTWEB-1-bztAlI1hzEaT"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: D4:D1:84:02:F0:80   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:914   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
-
```

Comment: The outputs above show that you are connected to a wireless AP. What do you mean by not working?

Comment: I meant it's not connecting to any webpage

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be related to DNS look-ups.  My system couldn't display websites because it wasn't able to look up their IP information via my DNS servers.

This was solved by resetting /etc/resolv.conf to:

```
# Use Google DNS
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```